# How to remove debug symbols executable MacOS

Tags: macos, build, release, debug-symbols

I am working on Qt application for MacOS. There, in order to debug I would like to build with debug symbols. For that, following Qt dos I have added

```
QMAKE_CFLAGS_RELEASE = $$QMAKE_CFLAGS_RELEASE_WITH_DEBUGINFO
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RELEASE = $$QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RELEASE_WITH_DEBUGINFO
QMAKE_OBJECTIVE_CFLAGS_RELEASE = $$QMAKE_OBJECTIVE_CFLAGS_RELEASE_WITH_DEBUGINFO
QMAKE_LFLAGS_RELEASE = $$QMAKE_LFLAGS_RELEASE_WITH_DEBUGINFO
```

I have checked and it works, symbols are there.

I would like to know if there is a way to remove those symbols AFTER BUILD. I have tried strip command on the executable but apparently it does nothing. This command:

```
otool -Iv build/MyApp.app/Contents/MacOS/MyApp
```

has same output after running strip. Could someone tell me how to effectively remove debug symbols? Also, the way I am using to check that symbols are gone, is it the right one ? If not how could I verify that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `strip` should work. Are still seeing private symbols after using it?

Comment: @TheNextman what should I see if there are no symbols as output?

Comment: If you run `nm` on your binary, the symbols are listed with their symbol type. Globally visible names (marked with `T`) will not be stripped.